# Preview Mouse Click - Windows Forms

Tags: onclick, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with controls - picture boxes. The form has an event mouse click. This event does not work when I click on a picture box. Is there a way to detect this click on the form no matter if there is a picture box or not. Thank you

Comment: That's entirely by design, the click goes to the PictureBox control of course.  An event handler for that control can do whatever it wants, including notifying the form class about it.